# Saving webview games score

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, save

I have a webview loading a local html,css, and javascript game through this line of code

`webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");`

Now what I'm wanting to do is be able to save the players score when he exits out of the app. But I really have no clue how I would do this from a local file. So if you could help that'd be great, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Since you "own" the game (it's part of your package), you can modify it right?

I'm not an android expert, but if the HTML is allowed to update window.location, then one easy way to do this would be for the game to add the the current score to the location hash.

i.e., find the javascript function that updates the score, and change it so that it also puts the score in window.location.hash (as opposed to the query string, to prevent the call from reloading the game). Maybe it looks like this:

```
function updateScore(newScore) {
  this.score = newScore;
  window.location.hash = "score=" + newScore;
}
```

Then you could just read the score out of the webView URL.